# OnEdit on a range in spreadsheet with some of the range in it as protected

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have two sheets namely `sheet1` and `sheet2`

I ave a drop down selector in `sheet1` and based on that certain columns in `sheet2` hide and unhide

- The drop-down selection has `sales` and `non sales` to be selected in sheet1
- In sheet2, only the range `AA:AH` are protected
- When a user when selects `sales` from the dropdown in sheet1 I am hiding the columns
  I am using an `onEdit` function

```
function onEdit(){
  main = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet1 = main.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var sheet2 = main.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  var dirpar_check = sheet1.getRange("J9").getValue();
  if (dirpar_check == "Sales"){
    
    sheet2.hideColumns(18,17);
  }
  else {
    sheet2.showColumns(18,17);
  }
}
```

the columns which should be hidden in sheet2 are `R:AH`, Now since the columns `AA:AH` here are protected. the script given an error -

`Exception: You are trying to edit a protected cell or object. Please contact the spreadsheet owner to remove protection if you need to edit.`

How can I make it work without having to remove the protection.
Please help!

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your current issue, I proposed a modification point as an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your current issue, I apologize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your situation, I'm worried that the reason for your current issue is due to that a simple trigger is used. So, in your script, how about changing the simple trigger to the installable trigger? So, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
function onEdit(){
```

#### To:

```
function installedOnEdit(){ // <--- Rename function name.
```

And, [please install OnEdit trigger to `installedOnEdit`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually). And, please test it again. By this flow, the script is run as the owner of the Spreadsheet. I thought that this might resolve your current issue.

Comment: Thank you @Tanaike san, I tried the below

```
function installedOnEdit(){
  main = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet1 = main.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var sheet2 = main.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  var dirpar_check = sheet1.getRange("J9").getValue();
  if (dirpar_check == "Sales"){
    
    sheet2.hideColumns(18,17);
  }
  else {
    sheet2.showColumns(18,17);
  }
}
```

but still I am getting same error - Exception: You are trying to edit a protected cell or object. Please contact the spreadsheet owner to remove protection if you need to edit.

Comment: @Alicia Stone Thank you for replying. From your reply, did you install the installable OnEdit trigger by the owner of Spreadsheet? If a user who is not the owner of Spreadsheet installed it, the same issue occurs. When the owner of Spreadsheet installs the installable OnEdit trigger and the user who is not the owner of Spreadsheet is edit the dropdown list, no error occurs. Because the script is run as the owner of Spreadsheet. I'm worried about who installed the OnEdit trigger.

Comment: @Alicia Stone By the way, when I tested your situation using your showing script, I confirmed that the same error occurred. And, when the installable OnEdit trigger is installed to the renamed function `installedOnEdit()` by the owner of Spreadsheet, I also confirmed that even when a user who is not the owner of Spreadsheet is run the script by changing the dropdown list, the script worked without the error. But, if I misunderstood your actual situation, I apologize.

Comment: I apologize @Tanaike -san. I missed the point where the owner of the spreadsheet should install the trigger. I will get this done.  Thank you so much

Comment: @Alicia Stone Thank you for replying. If the user who is not the owner of Spreadsheet has already installed the OnEdit trigger, please remove the installed OnEdit trigger by the user. And, please install the installable OnEdit trigger by the owner of Spreadsheet, and test it again.

Comment: Thank you @ Tanaike - San, have done the same as you suggested, and it works like a charm. Thanks a ton!

Comment: oops, sorry I missed that

Comment: @Alicia Stone Thank you for your response. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Comment: Tanaike - san, there is one problem here, when I make a copy of this spreadsheet the triggers set are not getting copied and hence the installedonEdittrigger is not working in the copy

Comment: san, I would want the copy of the sheet also to automatically have the trigger installedOnEdit trigger set up by the owner whenever a copy is made

Comment: @Alicia Stone About your new request of `I would want the copy of the sheet also to automatically have the trigger installedOnEdit trigger set up by the owner whenever a copy is made`, I would like to support you. But., I think that this is a new question. So, can you post it as a new question? By this, it will help users including me to think of a solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your new question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: sure Tanaike-San, I will post it as a new question. Thank you

Comment: I have posted new question here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75969887/installedonedit-trigger-also-to-be-copied-when-a-copy-of-spreadsheet-is-made