# installedOnEdit trigger also to be copied when a copy of spreadsheet is made

Tags: google-apps-script

I have an `installedOnEdit` trigger used because I was hiding and unhiding columns which were protected based on a condition. Now, I had the trigger added by the owner of the sheet.

I do make copies of this spreadsheet and share with stakeholders to get inputs. While making of the spreadsheet, the scripts do get copied over but the triggers won't.

How can this `installedOnEdit` also be copied over to every copy of the sheet which is made.

We can use a button, so whenever any user creates a copy they must click the button to create the trigger.
or some other way without having to use a button.

Comment: About `We can use a button, so whenever any user creates a copy they must click the button to create the trigger.`, I would like to ask about the detail of this situation. In your actual situation, when the Spreadsheet is copied, who is the owner of the copied Spreadsheet?

Comment: @Tanaike - san the one copying the spreadsheet is the owner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You have a Google Spreadsheet.
- Your Spreadsheet is shared with a user as the writer.
- Your Spreadsheet has a button for executing a script for copying the active Spreadsheet.
- Your Spreadsheet has a function `installedOnEdit` for executing by the installable OnEdit trigger.
- You want to make the user copy the active Spreadsheet by clicking the button, and also, you want to automatically install the OnEdit trigger to `installedOnEdit` for the copied Spreadsheet, simultaneously.

Unfortunately, I cannot know your script for copying the Spreadsheet and `installedOnEdit`. So, in this answer, I would like to explain the method for achieving your goal using a simple sample script.

### Usage

Please do the following flow.

#### Preparation

1. Please create a new Google Spreadsheet and please copy the paste the following script to the script editor and save the script. In this case, you are the owner of the Spreadsheet.

   ```js
   // This is a simple sample script for executing by the installable OnEdit trigger.
   function installedOnEdit(e) {
     const { range } = e;
     range.setValue(`Updated ${range.getValue()}`);
   }

   // It supposes that this function is run by clicking a button by a user.
   function copySpreadsheet() {
     const functionName = "installedOnEdit"; // This function is installed as OnEdit trigger.

     const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
     const copiedSpreadsheet = ss.copy("Copied_" + ss.getName());
     ScriptApp.newTrigger(functionName).forSpreadsheet(copiedSpreadsheet).onEdit().create();
     const html = `<a href="${copiedSpreadsheet.getUrl()}" target="_blank">Open copied Spreadsheet</a>`;
     SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html).setWidth(300).setHeight(100), "sample");
   }
   ```
2. Please share this Spreadsheet with another user as a writer.
3. Please set the sheet name. And, please install OnEdit trigger to the function `installedOnEdit`. And, please create a button and assign the function name of `copySpreadsheet` to the button. By this, when this button is clicked, the script of `copySpreadsheet` is run.
4. As a test, please put a value of "sample" to a cell of "Sheet1". And, please confirm that the inputted value of "sample" is changed to "Updated sample". By this, the preparation is finished.

#### Testing

As a test, please open the Spreadsheet with the shared user. And, please click a button. By this, `copySpreadsheet` is run. And, the active Spreadsheet is copied and the function `installedOnEdit` is installed as the OnEdit trigger. In this case, the owner of the copied Spreadsheet is the user who clicked the button, because when a script is run by a button, the script is run as the user who clicked. This method uses this situation.

When this method is used, the following result is obtained.

[image]

### IMPORTANT

- As an important point, in this method, the script of `installedOnEdit` on the original Spreadsheet (the owner of this Spreadsheet is you.) is used as the installable OnEdit trigger. So, when you modify the script of `installedOnEdit`, `installedOnEdit` for the copied Spreadsheet is also changed. Please be careful about this.
- This is a simple script for explaining this method. So, please reflect this method in your actual script.

### References

- [Using OnEdit Trigger to Google Spreadsheet by Hiding Google Apps Script from Other Users (Author: me)](https://tanaikech.github.io/2023/01/25/using-onedit-trigger-to-google-spreadsheet-by-hiding-google-apps-script-from-other-users/)
- [Using OnEdit trigger on Google Spreadsheet Created by Service Account (Author: me)](https://tanaikech.github.io/2023/01/25/using-onedit-trigger-on-google-spreadsheet-created-by-service-account/)