Copying a Template Google Sheet with triggers on GAS
I have a Google Sheet that I have created and want to make multiple instances of. These copies are to be created by end users (other Google accounts) as follows.
I use dropdowns that, with an on edit trigger, run different scripts in libraries, one of which copies the sheet to a desired folder. I have been able to do this and even copy the Protection Ranges (which takes a lot of time) but have completely failed to add the same edit trigger to the newly copied file.
Moreover, when I get other users to add the edit trigger, the functions don't run well because of restrictions - i.e. some of the sheets that the functions use are not meant to be visible to the end users. I will need to give the user that creates the trigger viewing and even editing rights to sensitive sheets (that are meant to be private) depending on the function run.
So how can I create a trigger on the newly copied sheet from my account? I.e. the end user runs a function from the template sheet which makes my user create the copied sheet. Now all I need to do is create a trigger on the copied sheet from my account.

About I use dropdowns that, with an on edit trigger, run different scripts in libraries, one of which copies the sheet to a desired folder., in this case, who is the owner of on edit trigger? If it's you, the owner of the copied Spreadsheet is also you. Is my understanding correct? Under this condition, do you want to install the OnEdit trigger for the function in the copied spreadsheet? If my understanding is correct, I guess these threads might be useful. https://stackoverflow.com/q/75969887 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/77590392 But, if I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

I want to clarify this part of the your issue as well some of the sheets that the functions use are not meant to be visible to the end users. I will need to give the user that creates the trigger viewing and even editing rights to sensitive sheets does this mean that your primary issue is coming from the fact that code requires access to some other Google Sheet which should not be accessible with them? If this is correct, have you looked at the options of Deploying the Web App to hide the sheet and let the WebApp act as Psudo- Api Endpoint?

@Tanaike yes you are right. I am the owner of the original sheet, the on edit trigger and all the libraries that have been added to the Apps Script project bounded to the original sheet. I am also currently the owner of the copied sheets. I want the copies to be exactly identical to the original sheet inclusive the triggers. Let me check through the links you sent. Thanks.

@4thAnd1 You are right in that I basically want to control and restrict users' access to certain parts of the sheet, but I want them to be able to initiate a new sheet when required and fill up some details which will be restricted to them at a later date when the document has passed to another stage. And yes I have other sheets with data that is required for the "document" sheets to work that I don't want end users to view. I will have a look at the Web App solution, haven't built such a project yet. If you have an example of how I could get them to act as psudo api endpoints kindly share

WebApp as a psudo-api
When a Web App is accessed, it will use the authentication scope of the one who deployed, this will take care of your issue about not sharing data that should only be visible to you, this is the workflow on a skeletal level just to give you an idea how to get started with this.
Breakdown of the setup of this sample workflow
This sample workflow works like this:
There is a "Server side" web app that when loaded will run an appscript function that pastes a value on a spreadsheet then there is a "client-side" code that fetches this web app using UrlFetchApp
Server-side
First I set up a project in appscript that has an associated web-app, this web app will serve as the "backend". This project is also connected to a spreadsheet then the web-app will then be fetched by another project(will be used by other users)
Client-side
The next step is for other users to have a spreadsheet that has an appscript associated with it then this appscript will call the function from the "server-side".
Using this idea, you can implement your goal of letting other users have a copy of your template sheet without them having access to restricted data.
Sample Codes
Server side(Code on your end)
Appscript file
/*This is just a sample functionality In this code block is where you will 
have your server-side logic that is appropriate to your needs*/
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('spreadsheet_id_here');
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var range = sheet.getRange("A1");
  range.setValue("Hello");
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
} 
function doGet(){
  myFunction();
   return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("index");
}

Html file
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <script>

      function onRun(){
        google.script.run.myFunction();
      }
      window.onload = onRun();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>

Client-side(code on other users' side)
Appscript file
function fetchWeb() {
  return UrlFetchApp.fetch("url_of_the_deployed_webapp_here");
}

Note:
When deploying a webapp, you will have to give anyone access which you can do on the first step of deploying the webapp. See Web Apps
References:
UrlFetchApp
Web AppsClass google.script.run

Hi 4thAnd1,
I tried playing around with Web Apps and to some success but the only issue now remains that the after copying is done, I have to add an onInstallableEdit(e) trigger to the copied file in order for them to run the same script as the template did.
When I do this, the trigger is created in the project where the ScriptApp.newTrigger call is made, which in this case is the Web App and not the copied sheet. Then I have a trigger in the Web App for each copy made through it.
Same applies with a standalone GAS project. The triggers aren't in the copied sheet's projects. Any idea?
